# Select only parent nodes that match the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get all the parent nodes that contain the `.export` class, any children node that has a parent with the `.export` the class should be skipped from the selection.

The nodes could appear anywhere in the tree but want any node that doesn't have a parent with that same class.

Having the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="export"> <!-- Select this one -->
    <div class="export"> <!-- SKIP this one -->
        <!-- Content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="export"> <!-- Select this one -->
    <!-- Some more content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get them using the jQuery `.not()` method like:

```js
console.log($(".export").not(".export .export").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="export">
  <!-- Select this one -->
  <div class="export">
    <!-- SKIP this one -->
    <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="export">
  <!-- Select this one -->
  <!-- Some more content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()` selector for query to skip that matches the query in the selector.

```
$('.export:not(.export >)')
```

Comment: jQuery is full of surprises. This doesn't appear to be documented, but it does work anyway.